# Full Text Search with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, lucene, full-text-search, sphinx

I want to implete the full text search(FTS) queries in my node js application. The database I am using is MySQL. I know that MySQL does have inbuild support for FTS but sadly it does not support Singular/Plurals, Synonyms and Inflectional words. 
There other FTS libraries available that can work with MySQl. Following are the two I am interested in

- Lucene
- Sphinx Search

I am very much sure that Shpinx Search has npm package and can be used with node js. I am not sure if Lucene can be used with node js ?

Please let me know if lucene can be used with node js if so provide the documentation for the same.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have several alternative like [query-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-engine) and [several other tools](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lucene) available for Lucene.

Also, if you want to use FTS with node, you could have a look to Norch like suggest [this answer on a look-alike topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17521591/2343558).

Best,

Answer (score 2):

Maintainer of `search-index` and `Norch` here. They might be what you are looking for. You can even use your MySQL database as a back end if you want.

https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index (the lib)

https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/norch (the server)